# Question regarding the orientation of Coxa servos in a HEXAPOD

Tags: rcservo, legged, hexapod

I'm making a Hexapod robot (this is my first robotics project ever) and I'm having a hard time deciding the orientation of the servo motors on the COXA section. The hexapod I'm making is based on [this](https://github.com/antdroid-hexapod/antdroid/wiki/Assembly-guide#vitamins) with MG996R servo motors

The problem is that all the Hexapod assembly guides I've read (including the one above which I'm using) say that the servos on the coxa link have to be installed in a way that the Zero angles (the angle the servos move to automatically when they're plugged in) of the servos should point to look like this from above: 
(the red circles are the servos in question)

[image]

I understand that the reason for setting up the zero angles of the coxa servos this way is so that the Hexapod can directly stand up when it is powered up (since the motors go to their zero angles on powering up).

Now here's the problem: the servos can only move forward from the zero angles and then back to the zero angles in COUNTER-CLOCKWISE direction and do not go backwards from the zero angles i.e not move in the opposite direction. Knowing this, I don't understand how I'm supposed to install the servos like in the picture since doing that would mean the motors on the LEFT side would not be able to turn in the clockwise direction for the tripod gait. Can anyone please explain me how I'm supposed to get the motors moving in clockwise direction for the tripod gait while keeping the zero angles set in the directions as shown in the picture?